# Get data from two collections mongoid

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

Hi all MongoDB/Mongoid fans!

I'm having a small problem with my schema design.

At the moment I have three models, `User`, `Post` and `Comment`. `User <- has_many -> Posts`, `Post <- belongs_to -> User`, `Post <- has_many -> Comments` and `Comment <- belongs_to -> Post, User`.

Now I need to list a feed with all the posts and comments, including the User object. Think Twitter timeline including comments. The comment need to have both the related post, post user and comment user object loaded.

Is this possible using Mongo & Mongoid or do I need to change my schema design? If so, any ideas?

Thx, Tobias

Comment: If you have the `Post`, can't you just get the user and comments with `@post.user` and `@post.comments`?

Comment: I need to create the timeline based on created_at. Post and comments should be mixed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do in order to properly scale your schema; along with provide for a rather simple document structure.  I would take and contain a single post in a document which has all the required information you need and do something like:

Posts Table:

```
{
   _id: mongoId,
   author_name:'Tobias',
   author_id: mongoId,
   post_content: 'hi this is my post',
   comments:[
       {
            "comment":"this is a comment",
            "user":"bob",
            "user_id":mongoId
       }, 

       {
            "comment":"this is a comment2",
            "user":"bob2",
            "user_id":mongoId
       }
   ]
  }
```

Then simply have a users table which holds the id / name and any other information you might want on the user.  The reason I've chosen to denormalize the author_name / user is for ease of representing this data in your view layer. It is much easier to write a quick map reduce function to go through and update names in the posts table (back end work) then to have to do multiple queries to fetch the information.  Having this rich embedded schema will help generate quick pages for you.

Just so i'm clear the author_name == user and author_id == user_id (just different naming schema to clarify where it is mostly for your app side code. but this is just an example and you can modify as you see fit.

Good Luck!

Comment: This looks interesting! But when a user change his name I need to update them in the embedded comments. Your talking about "map reduce function". Would you like to be a little more detailed about it? Thx

Comment: Sandelius, also note that you would do this in mongoid using the embeds_many, embedded_in macros. Re: map/reduce, you probably don't need to do it that way, a simple update query on the post collection will most likely suffice.